# Randomly NoneType object is not callable error

Tags: python

Recently I've got this problem in my application:

> File "main.py", line 31, 
>   in File "app.pyc", line 205, in run
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"

My code:

```
xml = EXML()
for pid, product in store.products.items():
    xml.addRow()
    xml.addCell((product['name']).encode('utf-8'), "String")
    xml.addCell((product['symbol']).encode('utf-8'), "String")
    xml.addCell((product['brand_name']).encode('utf-8'), "String") # line 205
    xml.addCell(str(product['price']), "String")
```

Python 2.7 32-bit

It's wired, because this showed up after ~1000 iterations, with out any previus problem.
This application scans online store to get current prices.
Firstly I thought that somewhere I missed someting, and as result there is `None.encode('utf-8')`, but no, and "".encode('utf-8') seems to work. Moreover, I can't reproduce this error on testing site, just sometimes shows up while hard-working with ~2500 products.
What are possible other sources of this error?

Comment: I agree with @Roman. In general, I find it a good practice to avoid long one-liners as you have in your code: You call a method on the result of a function on a result of a method - It's harder to understand, and when you encounter an error somewhere it's significantly harder to find. In addition, you may try running your application with `python -i` to invoke the interpreter once the script run is terminated, then `import pdb` and invoke `pdb.pm()`. This Should open up a Pdb session on your last traceback and allow you to inspect just what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> None.encode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
>>> None()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

On the given line you would have to set one of the two functions called to `None` somehow. Are you sure it's not the next line, because overwriting `str` is a rather common error.

Comment: I'm sure str is not overwritten. I suppose something bad happens when I handle urllib2.HTTPException or AttributeError in my parser. I've noticed one more behave: in my script I was closing file handle before reading, and only sometimes it raised error.

Answer (score 0):

OK, solved, it's bit bizzare, but this error is caused by `product['brand_name']` which is sometimes `BeautifulSoup.tag` ( 
 tag this time ) instead of `BeautifulSoup.NavigableString` as I planned. I still don't understad why and wtf ?

Anywat, great thanks for response. :)